# Random number within range (range changes after each run)

Tags: c++, random

I'm trying to make a guess my number program, with the computer guessing the number that I choose, I seem to have finally got it working except for the random number range, the high number works but the low number doesn't,

I guess I shouldn't be doing lowGuess=rand() but I have no idea what I should be doing instead, could somebody point me in the right direction please?

Also feel free to give me feedback on the rest of the code, this is my first attempt at writing something myself. (with a little reference material)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

const int high = 100;
const int low = 1;
int lowGuess = 1;
int highGuess = 100;
int myNumber = 0;
int guess = 0;
int guesses = 0;
bool correct = 0;

int askNumber();
int askResponse();
int guessNumber();

int main()
{
    askNumber();

    do
    {
        guessNumber();
        askResponse();
    } while (correct == 0);
    cout << "Yes!! I guesed your number in " << guesses << " guesses.";

    return 0;
}

int askNumber()
{
    cout << "\n\nEnter a number between " << low << " - " << high << ".\n\n";
    cin >> myNumber;

    if (myNumber < low || myNumber >high)
    {
        return askNumber();
    }
}

int guessNumber()
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
    lowGuess = rand();                              //im   doing something wrong here with lowGuess
    guess = (lowGuess % highGuess) + 1;             //im trying to generate a random number between
    cout << "\n\nMy guess is " << guess << endl;    //the value of lowGuess and highGuess
    guesses += 1;                                   //highGuess is working as intended but lowGuess isn't

    //printing values to see them working
    cout << "low " << lowGuess << " high " << highGuess << endl;

    return 0;
}

int askResponse()
{
    int response;
    cout << "\n\nIs my guess too high, too low, or correct?\n\n";
    cout << "1. Too High.\n";
    cout << "2. Too Low.\n";
    cout << "3. Correct.\n\n";

    cin >> response;
    if (response < 1 || response > 3)
    {
        return askResponse();
    }
    else if (response == 1)
    {
        cout << "\n\nToo high eh? I'll take another guess.\n\n";
        highGuess = guess;              //altering the upper limit of random number range
    }
    else if (response == 2)
    {
        cout << "\n\nToo low eh? I'll take another guess.\n\n";
        lowGuess = guess;               //alteing the lower limit of random number range
    }
    else if (response == 3)
    {
        correct = 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: int askNumber() does not return in all cases

Comment: feedback: there's a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site you may wish to post your edited code to, and you'll get detailed help there on your style.

Comment: [OT]:  initialize `srand` only once.

Comment: @UKMonkey: It is for working code, whereas OP's code is buggy.

Comment: You may use something like `guess = low + (rand() % (high - low))`. Or even better, use the new `<random>` and [`uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution).

Comment: @Jarod42 updated comment to match what I was thinking

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, @Jarod42 I will look into the <random> code, where I learnt from didn't have this, hence what I used.

Comment: @willll Ah I see now, I must of deleted return 0; from the end by accident, it did work before, just realised when I tryed to run it again.

Comment: @Jarod42 I couldn't make the <random> method work so I went with guess = low + (rand() % (high - low)), I also needed to delete lowGuess = rand(); and change highGuess = guess; to highGuess = guess-1;.   It seems to work perfectly now. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`srand` should be called only once, usually in `main`. If you call `srand` every time with the same seed then the next `rand()` will always be the same.

Change `guessNumber` function to

```
int guessNumber()
{
    guess = lowGuess + rand() % (highGuess - lowGuess);
    cout << "\n\nMy guess is " << guess << endl;    
    guesses += 1;                                   
    cout << "low " << lowGuess << " high " << highGuess << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

For example `20 + rand() % 50` will generate a number between zero to 20 to 70.

Comment: By the way, you are not using the `return` value so change the function declaration to `void guessNumber();`, same with function definition `void guessNumber(){}` and don't return any values.

Answer (score 1):

With `<random>` from C++11, you may do something like:

```
int guessNumber(int low, int high, std::mt19937& eng)
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist(low, high);

    auto guess = uniform_dist(eng);
    std::cout << "My guess is " << guess << std::endl;
    return guess;
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/NdJ2wz)